# Decompressing by piping to zlib Gunzip instance fails, but decompressing with macOS finder succeeds

Tags: node.js, gzip

What's the best way to debug this? I feel like I'm just probing around with listening to different events and changing some configs. It's unclear why I'm unable to decompress my file in node.js while it's simple in macOS finder.

```
const zlib = require('zlib');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
  await process().catch(console.error);
})();

async function process() {
  const start = new Date();
  console.log(start);

  const outputFilePath = 'temp.tsv';
  const readStream = fs.createReadStream('input.tsv.gz');

  const gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();

  readStream.pipe(gunzip);
  readStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(outputFilePath));

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    gunzip.on('error', reject);

    readStream.on('error', reject);
    readStream.on('close', reject);
    readStream.on('end', resolve);
  });

  console.log(fs.statSync(outputFilePath));
  console.log(new Date(), (new Date() - start) / 1000);
}
```

The only pattern I'm noticing is that temp.tsv is significantly smaller size than the actual decompressed file. The output of temp.tsv is definitely not tsv as expected. It's jumbled & an unknown serialization to me at this point.

Comment: calling `gunzip.resume()` (after the 2 pipe calls) actually makes the output file size bigger, but not the full size of the actual expected output and the serialization is still not tsv

Answer (score 0):

The trick was I had to use whatever the previous pipe yielded. `pipe` is a type of `stream.Writable` so some events change (`finish` instead of `end`).

```
const zlib = require('zlib');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
  await process().catch(console.error);
  console.log('done');
})();

async function process() {
  const start = new Date();
  console.log(start);

  const inputFilePath = 'input.tsv.gz';
  const outputFilePath = 'temp.tsv';
  
  const pipe = fs.createReadStream(inputFilePath)
    .pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(outputFilePath));
  
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pipe.on('error', reject);
    pipe.on('close', reject);
    pipe.on('finish', resolve);
  });
  
  console.log('output file', fs.statSync(outputFilePath).size / 1024 / 1024, 'MB');
  console.log(new Date(), (new Date() - start) / 1000);
}
```